# When I run phx.server, what compile time gaurantees do I get?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm a little uncertain as to what compile time safety checks I get with elixir + phoenix.

I am familiar with ruby and scala, so where would something like elixir + phoenix be in terms of compile time checks/safety?

It seems to pickup allot of things that Rails wouldn't, but for some things (I can't recall) it didn't seem to validate.

Answer (score 1):

There's not that many compile-time guarantees in Elixir/Erlang, and it's rather similar to Ruby in that respect. The compiler will check that the functions you call actually exist with the arity you call them with, but even that does not always happen. For example, if you just put the following in a `.ex` file:

```
defmodule A do
  def a(), do: B.b()
end
```

And compile it with `elixirc my_file.ex`, it will not produce an error, but this:

```
defmodule A do
  def a(), do: b()
end
```

will produce one.

If you want to make more compile-time checks you might want to look into [dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir) to check the type annotations that Elixir allows you to include.